# WRITE PERMISSION DENIED - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was creating a simple Time Monitoring System that records the Time In and Time out of the user and record it in a txt file named "time_monitoring.txt".

Now, whenever I run the app in my phone, which is an Android 13, it shows that the write permission was denied.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TimeRecorder"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.timerecorder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnTimeIn, btnTimeOut;
    private TextView txtDateTime, txtFilePath;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTimeIn = findViewById(R.id.btnTimeIn);
        btnTimeOut = findViewById(R.id.btnTimeOut);
        txtDateTime = findViewById(R.id.txtDateTime);
        txtFilePath = findViewById(R.id.txtFilePath);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

        btnTimeIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recordTime("Time In");
            }
        });

        btnTimeOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recordTime("Time Out");
            }
        });

        // Inside the onCreate method, after initializing buttons and TextViews
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }

    private void recordTime(String eventType) {
        String currentTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String record = eventType + ": " + currentTime + "\n";

        // Update the TextView
        txtDateTime.setText(record);

        // Save the record to the file on SD card
        String filePath = saveToSDCard(record);

        // Show a toast message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recorded: " + eventType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Update the file path TextView
        txtFilePath.setText("File saved at: " + filePath);
    }

    private String saveToSDCard(String record) {
        try {
            File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "time_monitoring");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(dir, "time_monitoring.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            bufferedWriter.write(record);
            bufferedWriter.close();

            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Write permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Write permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTimeIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time In"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTimeOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time Out"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnTimeIn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnTimeOut"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFilePath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDateTime"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I expect to happen, when I click the Time In or Time Out button, it will add something like this in the "time_monitoring.txt": Time In: 11/30/2023 06:43:15.

Comment: The getExternalFilesDir() has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. And you do not need any permission to create files there.

Comment: Change to: if (!dir.exists()) {
                if(!dir.mkdirs()) return null;
            } And caller should check for null.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

```java
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

This is for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, which is not the same thing as `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

```java
            File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "time_monitoring");
```

`getExternalFilesDir()` does not require any permissions. So, the simple solution is to stick with that and get rid of your `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` manifest entry and your `requestPermissions()` call for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

there are two things to keep in mind
1.Check Permission Before Using Features:
Ensure you check whether the permission is granted before performing operations that require it. The code in recordTime is executing regardless of whether the permission is granted. You might want to check the permission status before attempting to write to the file:
2.Check Permission Again After Request:
After requesting permissions, you might want to check the result in onRequestPermissionsResult and proceed with the file operations only if the permission is granted.